# Explain javascript and php code

Tags: javascript, php

I got this code from internet, it works correctly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"?>   
</script>
<?php echo  $abc;?>
```

But when I put the `</script>` at the end it stops working, kindly explain why it stops working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"?>   
<?php echo  $abc;?>
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot place a `script` tag inside `script` tag

Comment: Change this `$abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"` to `$abc = "document.write(jvalue)"` and it should work

Comment: use "...<\/script>" to prevent the invalid script tag closer in JS

Comment: you got that code internet and dont know what that code does ? than you should rather read javascript and php first

Comment: @obiNullPoiиteяkenobi I know what that code does I didn't said explain what that code does, I have worked in both javascript and php. I was only asking what is "WRONG" in second code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `abc` is `<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>` and you can't nest the `<script>` tag. As your second example does. You could do,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';
    <?php $abc = "document.write(jvalue)"?>   
    <?php echo  $abc;?>
</script>
```

You could also do,

```
<?php $abc = "document.write(jvalue)"?>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';
    <?php echo  $abc;?>
</script>
```

which I think is more in keeping with the original example.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is not correct. According to the W3 HTML specification, a script tag cannot be inside another script tag. For future debugging purposes, try putting the entire output string through a validation check (validator.w3.org). This will inform you about coding mistakes and will help you understand the errors on which you can act.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong about this answer, I added an upvote to equal out the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The code you got will produce html like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';

</script>
<script>
  document.write(jvalue)
</script>
```

But the code you changed will produce like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';
   <script>
     document.write(jvalue)
   </script>
</script>
```

You cannot write script tag inside a script tag. That's why it producing error

Answer (score 1):

When php echos your variable `$abc`, the result is approximately:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';
    <script>document.write(jvalue)</script> 
</script>
```

Which is invalid as you can't place a script tag within another script tag (aka "nest").

Removing the `<script>` tags from `$abc` should fix it.

The following would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';
    <?php $abc = "document.write(jvalue)" ?> 
    <?php echo $abc; ?> 
</script>
```

I'm not a PHP expert, but I would expect that if $abc is not needed elsewhere in your code, those two PHP lines can be replaced with:

```
<?php echo "document.write(jvalue)"; ?>
```